I contacted SE via contact form and didn't receive the ticket
About an hour ago I contacted Stack Exchange via the contact form (https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and I didn't receive the ticket by e-mail until now, is there any staff here who can check this for me please?

Yes, we have received your ticket, and it is currently being worked on. Thank you again for reaching out, and please be patient as we thoroughly investigate this situation.

Ok, thank you very much for your feedback and attention, I will wait, thank you!

Isn't there email sent when the ticket is being reviewed, though?

Tl;dr you won't get a confirmation email (like "ticket received) unless it was submitted on a weekend. You need to wait until an SE employee responds. You might see it here.

I'm not staff, but...
If you submitted the ticket on a weekend, you'll get a response like this:

Hello!
Please be aware that the support team does not monitor support tickets during the weekend or holidays.
If you are on one of our Stack Overflow for Teams Enterprise or Business plans, we do offer on-call support. If this is an emergency, please open a Severity 1 or 2 ticket via our support portal. If your issue falls within our on-call SLA, someone should contact you within 15 minutes. For all other products and plans, we'll reach out as soon as we can the next business day.
Thanks

As far as I'm aware, if it's not a weekend, you won't get an autoreply (i.e., you won't get a follow-up email until a Stack Exchange employee responds).
That said, as blackgreen notes, the ticket may be visible here. In my personal experience, that doesn't always work, but that also might be because of my account, so it might work fine for you.

This is not true, I recently opened a ticket on a business day and received an email almost immediately containing the ticket number.

Regarding accessing the website cited by you (https://stackenterprise.freshdesk.com/support/tickets), I tried, but I couldn't log in, I sent an e-mail to a specific Stack Overflow support team about this.

"opened a ticket": I meant that I contacted SE via contact form.

Yep, I had to ask for help before I was able to log into that portal. That isn't something we can fix without staff :(

Yes, exactly...
